# How can I use a variable initialized in beforeEach in my test description?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I run several tests in a loop and I'd like to use a variable that is in the beforeEach on my test description

```
for(let i =0; i<3; i++){
        describe("action", () => {
          let variableToUse: string;
          beforeEach(async () => {
            variableToUse = await someAction(i);
          });
            it("some test desc " + variableToUse, async () => {
             //some test using variableToUse
            });
        });
}
```

I expect the console to show "some test desc varaibleToUseValue" but the actual output is "some test desc undefined"

Comment: Also make sure your someAction method should return a value and saves in the variabletouse variable, it seems that the problem with the method.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would do it this way

```
for(let i =0; i<3; i++){
    let variableToUse: string;
    describe("action", () => {
        beforeEach(async () => {
            variableToUse = await someAction(i);
        });
        it("some test desc " + variableToUse, async () => {
            //some test using variableToUse
        });
    });
}
```

In this case you'd be safe from reusing a value prom previous execution by accident, since it always is defined inside of a loop

Answer (score 0):

```
let variableToUse: string;
for(let i =0; i<3; i++){
        describe("action", () => {
          beforeEach(async () => {
            variableToUse = await someAction(i);
          });
            it("some test desc " + variableToUse, async () => {
             //some test using variableToUse
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: I tried moving the declaration above the loop but it's still undefined, thanks though

Comment: do share your complete spec file for give better input on the issue

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
describe('testbeforeeach - ', function () {
  var TestSuiteName = this.getFullName();
  var TestVariable = null;    
  beforeEach(function () {
   TestVariable = "abc";
    return TestVariable;
  });    
  it(TestSuiteName + 'Test1', function () {        
      console.log("TestVariable for Test1 ====", TestVariable);        
  });    
  it(TestSuiteName + 'Test2', function () {       
      console.log("TestVariable for Test2 ====", TestVariable);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below given code snippet

```
let variableToUse: number;

let i: number;

for(i =0; i<3; i++){
    describe("action", async () => {

      beforeEach(async () => {
         variableToUse =  i;
      });
        it("some test desc " + variableToUse, async () => {
         //some test using variableToUse
        });
    });
}
```